# Azure 504 DeploymentTimedOut ERROR - Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy my machine learning model in Azure's AciWebservice to expose endpoints for further usage. But, it is showing me status 504 error with DeploymentTimedOut.  Locally, My Model is running fine. This is my prediction.py

```
%%writefile prediction.py
import json
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.webservice import LocalWebservice, Webservice

def init():
    global model
    # retrieve the path to the model file using the model name
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('prediction_model')
    model = joblib.load(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    data = np.array(json.loads(raw_data)['data'])
    # make prediction
    y_hat = model.predict(data)
    return json.dumps(y_hat.tolist())
```

and here goes the environment

```
myenv = Environment(name="myenv")
myenv.docker.enabled = True
myenv.docker.base_image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/o16n-sample-user-base/ubuntu-miniconda"


myenv.docker.base_image_registry.address = "shohozds.azurecr.io"
myenv.docker.base_image_registry.username = "farhad"
myenv.docker.base_image_registry.password = "*********************"

myenv.inferencing_stack_version = "latest" 


conda_dep = CondaDependencies()

conda_dep.add_pip_package("azureml-defaults")
myenv.python.conda_dependencies=conda_dep
myenv.register(workspace=ws)
```

Using this environment in InferenceConfig

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script="prediction.py",
                                   environment=envs['myenv'])
```

AciWebservice Configuration

```
deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 1, memory_gb = 1)
```

And now the model deployment

```
service = Model.deploy(ws, "myservice", [model], inference_config, deployment_config)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

But I am facing this error

```
"code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
"statusCode": 504,
```

This is the full trace

```
ERROR - Service deployment polling reached non-successful terminal state, current service state: Unhealthy
Operation ID: 0e37b930-2707-4d6b-92b0-2203d1c45978
More information can be found using '.get_logs()'
Error:
{
  "code": "DeploymentTimedOut",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "The deployment operation polling has TimedOut. The service creation is taking longer than our normal time. We are still trying to achieve the desired state for the web service. Please check the webservice state for the current webservice health. You can run print(service.state) from the python SDK to retrieve the current state of the webservice."
}
```

Comment: have you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are there is something failing during initialization time which causes the service to remain in an unhealthy state.

Per the error message, you can run `service.get_logs()` to get log information from the unhealthy service to see what's causing it to fail. If I had to guess, glancing at your code, it's likely an issue with get_model_path, but the logs will say for sure.

More information on how to debug a failing service can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment).

Comment: `service.get_logs()` is `None`